# Put marker and find code location in binary with hex editor (to test)

Tags: c++

I have zero 'hacker' skills and once the code is compiled, the executable is more or less a black box to me.

I am trying to find where a particular line of code ends up in the binary.
This is to test my own code to see how often, where, etc. the code is put in the binary, to test the effects of changes I'm making in both debug and release builds.

I tried adding some code before or after the line I'm interested in.  Like so:

```
char *test = "Tr@ck" ;
```

but I believe "Tr@ck" is put in the resources somewhere (Is that correct?) so I don't think if I search for this string with a hex editor I will find it where the code really resides ?

So I was wondering if a small piece of assembler code would work instead ?
Something that is totally inert in itself, will not change anything, but is easy to look for with a hex editor ?
(Or 'something' c/c++ that achieves the same.)

Would that work ?
Can you recommend something ?
Never added assembler before, so if that is the solution, kindly provide an example.

FYI, Using Borland C++ Builder 2009.

Comment: For the love of Turing, *please* use a modern compiler.

Comment: You're correct that the string you chose will be placed in a read-only section (probably) of the object file(s) — it probably won't be in the resources — and may be shared if you use the same tracker multiple times, and generally won't tell you anything about where your code is in the executable (only that it is there).  I don't think there's an easy way to locate 'where'.

Comment: I actually managed to achieve what I wanted to do by first making sure a particular binary value (for instance: 0x1111FFFE) was not present in the executable.  Next I put `DWORD test = 0x1111FFFE ;` before and after the line I wanted to test.  Doing this I could locate the code and play with it.